# Html footer content non centered

Tags: html, css

I want to center a button in the bottom of the page:

```
<footer>
    <div class="centerContent">
        <input name="submit" type="submit" />
    </div>
</footer>
```

**Css:**

```
.centerContent {
    text-align: center;
}

footer {
    clear: both;
    height: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

If I remove the "footer" part of the Css, the button is not in the bottom of the page of course, but at least it is in the horizontal center of the page. If I leave the "footer" part in the Css, the button is in the bottom of the page but.....it is not horizontally centered anymore!!! Anybody knows why? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For horizontal align, you should stretch footer to full width. Add `width:100%` to `footer` style.

```
.centerContent {
    text-align: center;
}

footer {
    clear: both;
    height: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: `footer: 100%;` OOps :)

Answer (score 0):

```
footer {
bottom: 0;
clear: both;
height: 100px;
position: absolute;
text-align: center;
width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try add width:100% to the footer

```
footer {
  width: 100%;
  clear: both;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

position: absolute will make the footer lose it's width by default.

Answer (score 0):

Add `left` and `right` properties to your `footer`, both set to `0`:

```
footer {
    clear: both;
    height: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;

    /* add the following lines */
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

If you add `width: 100%` instead (as other answers suggest), your `footer` might spread the page out because of any additional margins and/or paddings.